# Recording sound output on a website

Tags: flash, audio, web, applet, multimedia

I am developing a music online mixer, and now I'm trying to record the sound from the sound output of the computer. It needs to be a web compatible solution. I've been looking around, and I've found solutions to record the microphone output, but not the standar sound output (by standard sound output I mean the one that goes to the speakers). I would like to know if anyone can recommend me a solution to do so.
Thanks very much for your help in advance

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to know if anybody knows a way to do so

Comment: what version / flavor of Flash are you using?

Comment: If you haven't even started yet, asking SO for help is a bit premature. At least decide on a development environment first.

Comment: I'll keep searching for a solution then, I haven't decided a development environment for this component of the app yet because I haven't found any information pointing to this particular functionality. Thanks anyway for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible using only scripts / plugins running in the browser, as far as I am aware.

However, if your user is using an OS and drivers (or even hardware) that allow them to loop back their output / stereo mix to an input, then they can do that part of the job for themselves.